# Preview image taken in a FlatButton

Tags: image, flutter

Hello fellow coders I come here again with a problem.
So I in my app the user completes a form then he has to take a picture this picture is saved in the phone using the [gallery_saver](https://pub.dev/packages/gallery_saver/example) and this works fine but I have to add a preview in my app of the picture which the user has took and I tried with one FlatButton which has a default image and this button when is clicked it will open the camera and after the user will make the photo and now comes my problem I want that after the user takes the picture the FlatButton image will update with the picture which the user has took (here is one  [website](https://iloves3.primarie3.ro/CityCareWeb/) that has something that I want to make, sorry that the website is not in english, when you open the website you have a tab next to "FILTRE" tab named "SEMNALEAZA PROBLEMA" click on this tab and then you will have 3 buttons with a camera icon on them.I want to do something like that when the user clicks on the icon it will take the picture and then the icon will update in the picture that the user has took).

I made a preview with some images:
[image]

The user will click on that button an then after uploads/take  a picture it will be like in the next image [image]

In java is pretty simple because we have iDs but in flutter I didn't notice something like this

This is how I take a picture:

```
void _takePhoto() async {
ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera).then((File image) {
  if (image != null && image.path != null) {
    setState(() {
      recordedImage = image;
      attachments.add(FileAttachment(recordedImage));
    });
    GallerySaver.saveImage(image.path).then((bool success) {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }
});
```

}

This is how my app looks:
[image]

And I want that after I click the circled button the user will take the picture using the code above and after the user takes the picture the default image from button will change in the picture which the user takes. But I don't know how to tell my app to change the image from FlatButton

This is my code for my buttons:

```
Container(
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    child:  FlatButton(
        child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/photo.svg'),
            onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                      
                });
             },
        ),
    ),
```

In setState() function there will be the function _takePicture and then I want to change the image from the FlatButton in the preview of the take picture

If you need more info about my code please feel free to ask

Comment: Can you explain what *exactly* your problem is? What is the problem showing the picture in the button?

Comment: @nvoigt The picture is not from my app it's from an website which does the thing I want my app to do I'll add pictures with my app in 2 minutes or so

Comment: @nvoigt done, I've added an image with my app and my problem

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out at what *exact* point you need help. So you snap a picture, I assume you know how to put it into a variable, lets say "picture1". You seem to know how to call "setState". Can you show a button **or** draw an image depending on whether "picture1" is null **or** not?

Comment: @nvoigt I added some more details but I don't really know exactly how to describe my problem

Comment: I don't know exactly how to change the image from the FlatButton after the user takes the picture

Comment: To put it simple if I was to change the code from child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/photo.svg'), to child:Image('path to the image which the user has taken')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the image picker example from the docs to add a button that would contain the picture once you took it:

```
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  File _image;
  final picker = ImagePicker();

  Future<void> getImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    if(pickedFile != null && pickedFile.path != null) {
      setState(() {
        _image = File(pickedFile.path);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Image Picker Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _image == null
            ? FlatButton(child: Text('Pick image.'), onPressed: getImage)
            : FlatButton(child: Image.file(_image), onPressed: getImage)
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll try this later because I run out of battery to my laptop. I didn't know how to do this part  _image = File(pickedFile.path); to set this thing. Forgot that I can put something like this final picker = ImagePicker(); thank you so much